# Is there such a thing as divided conduit?

Tags: wiring, conduit

The excacator is coming to visit, and this is my opportunity to prepare for lighting, a possible gate motor, and a possible camera. I know I can't just pull both cat6 and power through a single pipe. There are pavers going in atop whatever I put in, so I do not want to have to ever dig it up.

Options, thus:

- Two conduits
- direct burial, which transgresses my desire to never have to dig to repair
- a hypothetical/mythical conduit that is divided into two raceways so that low-voltage travels up one side while house current runs down the other.

I ask about the third possibility here because I'm not sure what terminology to use to look for this mythical beast. (Which, of course, might turn out to be more expensive than just laying two ordinary ones.)

Comment: You can put fiber and power in the same conduit. Anyway gates don't actually need enough power to justify running AC mains to them.  They are amply served by modest solar and battery, with the bonus that power outages don't lock you in lol.

Comment: Fiber, well, that's another kettle of beans. I may need a 'gate' consisting of a section of wooden fence that moves, somewhat uphill, in parallel with the rest of the fence. I guess I have a whole other set of research to do.

Comment: Also, you know, _significant_ lighting. I've only seen motion-activated outdoor lighting for mains wiring. Next research; is there a version that runs off of low-voltage.

Comment: They make it. They even make discrete motion sensors separate from lights so you can assemble your own, and they're half the cost of AC ones because they are simpler (no 120->12V conversion needed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is "innerduct" which is basically a close cousin of ENT to be run inside another conduit. Practically speaking, just run two conduits.

The conduit with the innerduct inside it has to be quite large, thus relatively expensive .vs. two smaller conduits suited to your needs.

Comment: Agree, two conduits. No one has *ever* said "I wish I had buried fewer conduits." Or smaller, either.